# Can I apply $\rho g h$ in fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

The pressure in a fluid at a depth $h$ below the free surface (due to liquid itself) is $\rho g h$ where $\rho$=density of the fluid. Does this apply to case when the liquid is in motion also by which I mean that I know that it is applicable in fluid statics but is it equally applicable in fluid dynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a small cube of water. Since, there are no shear forces in a *static* fluid, pressure at any place is same in all directions.

The net force in the cube exerted in the faces perpendicular to $x$ axis parallel to the base of the cube (neglecting higher order derivatives of $p$) is given by $(p - \left(p + \partial_x p~\Delta x\right))\Delta y\Delta z$ where '$\partial_x$' denotes the partial derivative with respect to $x\,.$

Similarly, taking into consideration all the other faces, the resultant force is 
$$-~(\partial_x p + \partial_y p + \partial_z p)~\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z = -~\nabla p ~\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\,.~~~~~~~~~\textrm{definition of gradient operator}$$

Then for the cube to be in equilibrium, $$-\nabla p + \mathrm F_\textrm{others} = 0\,.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\textrm{Newton's Second Law of Motion}$$

If the force can be expressed as the gradient of a scalar potential $\varphi,$ per unit mass, then

$$\underbrace{-\nabla p - \rho\nabla \varphi = 0}_\textrm{equation of hydrostatics}\,.\tag{I}$$

If $\rho$ is constant, then the second term is a pure gradient term. Hence,

$$\begin{align}\nabla(p +\rho\cdot \varphi)  &= 0\\ \implies~~~~~~~~ p + \rho \cdot \varphi &= \textrm{constant} \end{align}$$

When the other force is gravity, then the equation of motion has the solution $$ p + \rho g h = \textrm{constant}\,.$$

---

In the general case, the shear stress  is non-zero for there exists *internal force* in the flowing fluid. So, there exists  *viscous* force $\mathbf F_\textrm{viscous force}$. Hence, the equation of motion for an element of fluid per unit volume is given by $$\rho \times (\textrm{acceleration}) = -\nabla p - \rho \nabla \varphi + \mathrm F_\textrm{viscous force} ~~~~\textrm{Newton'
s Second Law of Motion}\tag{II}$$

where

$\begin{align}\textrm{acceleration} \equiv \dot{\mathbf v}(x,y,z,t) & =  v_x ~\partial_x\mathbf v + v_y ~\partial_y \mathbf v  + v_z~\partial_ z \mathbf v + \partial_t \mathbf v \\ & = (\mathbf v\cdot\nabla) ~\mathbf v + \partial_t \mathbf v\tag{III}\,.\end{align}$

Putting $\rm (III)$ in $\rm (II),$ we get

$$\underbrace{\frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} +(\mathbf v\cdot\nabla )~\mathbf v = -\frac{\nabla p}{\rho} -\nabla \varphi + \frac{\mathbf F_\textrm{viscous force}}{\rho}}_\textrm{General equation of motion of a  fluid element per unit volume}\,.\tag{IV}$$

---

> Can I apply $\rho gh$ in fluid dynamics

When the other force is gravitational force, then $\varphi = gh\,.$

However, the crux of the post is that in case, the fluid is *moving*, the equation of motion is not $\rm (I)$ anymore; then you have to use the general $\rm(IV)$ for further analysis of the problem.

### References:

$\bullet$ *Lectures on Physics* Vol. 2 by *Feynman, Leighton, Sands*.

Comment: Given the tone of the OP (and therefore its likely future audience), this answer will probably benefit from a layman's summary of what the math means.

Comment: Thanks @Emilio, for the response; could you tell me explicitly what point I need to expand? The purpose of the post was to show that when the other force is gravity, $\rho g h$ can be used; but the equation of motion won't be same. Both the cases have been briefly discussed here prior to the jotting down of the equation of motion which is basically just the second law. I'll be happy to add more if you tell me what I should add specifically.

Comment: That's for you to evaluate and think about critically. The OP (and future visitors along with him) is asking about $\rho gh$, which is a highschool-physics concept. Do you think the equation-of-motion formalism as you have developed it here is accessible and understandable to that demographic? We're not here to hold your hand; you're here to hone your communication skills, and that includes thinking carefully about who you're writing for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [Bernoulli's Equation](http://www.princeton.edu/~asmits/Bicycle_web/Bernoulli.html) :
$$p+\frac12\rho v^2+\rho gh = constant$$
along a streamline, assuming the fluid is incompressible (constant density) and there is no viscosity, and flow is laminar (not turbulent) and steady (there is no acceleration along a streamline).

This equation contains the term $\rho g h$ and applies to fluids in motion. Note that the kinetic energy of the fluid must also be taken into account, in the term $\frac12 \rho v^2$. It is a statement of the conservation of energy (PE+KE).

Comment: ...assuming [...] *and* that the flow is laminar, i.e. not turbulent.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : I think that assumption is included in "along a streamline" because turbulent flow has no streamlines.

Comment: @sammy It bears making that explicit, given the tone of the OP - it may not be quite clear just how important that assumption is.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty : Fair point. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: So in fluid dynamics also, the pressure at a depth $h$ from free surface is $\rho g h$ when fluid is not accelerating.

Comment: ... When the fluid is *not moving at all*. Note the $\frac12\rho v^2$ term. Motion of fluid $(v>0)$reduces pressure $p$ if $h$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The hydrostatic contribution $\rho g h$ is present when the fluid is in motion, but the total pressure the fluid experiences (which is what is measured by a pressure gauge) can, and usually does, have other contributions too. For example if a pump is driving the flow through a horizontal pipe, hydrostatic contribution to pressure is the same along pipe's length, but there would still be a pressure variation along pipe's length because of pump's action on the fluid. Usually in fluid dynamics, we split the total pressure as: $p_{total}=\rho g h+p_{other}$. In static fluid, $p_{other}$ would be zero (more correctly, $\nabla p_{other}=0$ in a static fluid, and we may simply set the constant value of $p_{other}$ to zero, i.e. take $p_{other}$ as the reference pressure).